# How are Jacobians of genus $3$ curves different from one another?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

There are two types of smooth projective (complex) curves of genus $3$: plane quartics, and hyperelliptic curves. The Torelli morphism $M_3\to A_3$, assigning a curve to its (principally polarized) Jacobian, is bijective on points. Thus $A_3$ consists of Jacobians of genus $3$ curves. Because of the "partition" of $M_3$ as {plane quartics} $\amalg$ {hyperelliptics}, I would expect this to be reflected somehow in $A_3$. Whence my questions:

**Question 1**. What are the main differences between Jacobians of plane quartics and of hyperelliptic curves?

(I am intentionally vague here, as I am curious about *any* sort of difference).

It would be also interesting to know if the deformation theory of the curve inside its Jacobian is sensibly different according to the curve itself; this leads to a second question:

**Question 2**. (Deformations inside the Jacobian) What do the normal bundles $\mathcal N_{C/Jac(C)}$ look like, when $C$ is a plane quartic or a hyperelliptic curve, respectively?

Thanks for any clue on this.

Comment: Careful! The map $M_3\to A_3$ is actually not surjective. I believe it was Beauville who showed that the complement $A_3\backslash M_3$ consists of non-simple ppavs with product polarizations.

Comment: As to your first question, all I can think of is a general property of hyperelliptic curves that is not shared by general curves, that says that the automorphism $-1$ of the Jacobian descends to the hyperelliptic involution on $C$ (if you embed $C$ the "right way" via a Weierstrass point).

Comment: Dear @RobertAuffarth: thanks for your comments. In particular, I did not think about reducible polarizations, thanks for pointing that out. Regards

Answer (score 3):

Let $L$ be a principal polarization on the Jacobian of the genus $3$ curve. Then $L^2$ gives an embedding of the Kummer variety $X$ of this Jacobian (i.e., quotient by the action $x \mapsto -x$). Khaled showed that this embedding is projectively normal (i.e., the restriction map

$Sym^n(H^0(X, L^2)) \to H^0(X, L^{2n})$

is surjective for all $n$) if and only if $C$ is not hyperelliptic. This was actually useful in a paper I wrote (and I will also take the opportunity to advertise): see Proposition 6.9 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.2575 and also the reference for Khaled's paper.

Answer (score 1):

For Question 2. From the conormal bundle sequence
$$0\to\mathcal N^{\vee}\to \Omega_{Jac(C)}\to \omega_C\to 0$$
we see that we can identify $\mathcal N^{\vee}$ with the kernel/syzygy bundle $M_{\omega_C}$ given by the exact sequence
$$0\to M_{\omega_C}\to H^0(C,\omega_C)\to\omega_C.$$
This bundle is semistable of slope $-2$ and if $g\geq 3$ it fails to be stable precisely for hyperelliptic curves. See (3.4)Corollary in [https://www.imsc.res.in/~kapil/papers/chap1/index.html](https://www.imsc.res.in/%7Ekapil/papers/chap1/index.html)

To see the instability appear for hyperelliptic curves, it is enough to observe sections of $M_{\omega_C}\otimes{\mathcal O}_C(H)$, where $H$ is the hyperelliptic pencil giving the $2:1$ map to $\mathbb P^1$, such that $h^0(C,H)=2$. Twisting in the sequence above and taking sections, we have
$$0\to H^0(C,M_{\omega_C}\otimes{\cal O}_C(H))\to\mathbb C^{2g}\to\mathbb C^{g+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**For Question 2**, a quick description of the normal bundle $N_{C|J(C)}$ is (See Lemma 3.8 of [1]):

$$h^0(C,N_{C|J(C)})=h^1(C,N_{C|J(C)})=
\begin{cases}
3 ~\text{for} ~C~\text{non-hyperelliptic}\\
4 ~\text{for} ~C~\text{hyperelliptic}.\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{cases}$$

This tells us some information of the deformation theory of the pair $(J(C),C)$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the deformation space of such pairs, for $C\in M_3$ and $J(C)$ the Jacobian of $C$, then the tangent space of $\mathcal{D}$ at $(J(C),C)$ is the hypercohomology $\mathbb{H}^1(J(C),C)$, which fits into the exact sequence

$$0\to H^0(J(C),T_{J(C)})\to H^0(C,N_{C|J(C)})\to \mathbb{H}^1(J(C),C)\xrightarrow{d} H^1(J(C),T_{J(C)})\to H^1(C,N_{C|J(C)})\to 0.$$

Using $T_{J(C)}\cong \mathcal{O}^{\oplus 3}_{J(C)}$, one has $h^0(J(C),T_{J(C)})=3$ and $h^1(J(C),T_{J(C)})=9$, together with $(\ref{1})$, one has $\dim \mathbb{H}^1(J(C),C)$ is always equal to $6$, so $\mathcal{D}$ is smooth, no matter $C$ is hyperelliptic or not.

However, the distinction comes from the rank of $d$, **which is the answer to your Question 2**:

*If $C$ is non-hyperelliptic, $d$ is of maximal rank, so when $J(C)$ deforms in the 6-dimensional p.p.a.v. locus, the curve $C$ deforms with $J(C)$; If $C$ is hyperelliptic, $d$ has a one-dimensional kernel, so $C$ will be obstructed when $J(C)$ deforms normal to the 5-dimensional hyperelliptic locus.*

The proof of $(\ref{1})$ is essentially a classical fact known as *Noether's theorem*, which states that $$\text{Sym}^2H^0(C,K_C)\to H^0(C,2K_C)$$ is an isomorphism when $C$ is non-hyperellptic curve and has a one-dimensional kernel when $C$ is hyperellptic.

**Question 1** is essentially answered in rfauffar's comment, namely  $\tau(C)$ coincides with $C$ up to a translation in torus if and only if $C$ is hyperelliptic, where $\tau:J(C)\to J(C)$ is the involution given by $(-1)$-map and we identify $C$ with its Abel-Jacobi image in $J(C)$.

I'd like to mention a theorem related to this fact. Note that $\tau$ always induces identity map on $H_2(J(C),\mathbb Z)$, so $\tau(C)$ is homologous to $C$ in $J(C)$, however, they are in general not algebraically equivalent:

***Theorem:*** (G. Ceresa [2], 1983) *When $C$ is general in $M_3$, $C$ is not algebraically equivalent to $\tau(C)$.*

Based on this result, F. Bardelli and M. Nori showed

***Theorem:*** (F. Bardelli [1], 1989, M. Nori [3], 1989) *Let $A$ be a general abelian threefold, the Griffiths group $\mathcal{G}_1(A)$ (the group of algebraically trivial 1-cycles modulo homological equivalence) is not finitely generated.*

[1] Bardelli, Fabio.
Curves of genus three on a general abelian threefold and the nonfinite generation of the Griffiths group. Arithmetic of complex manifolds (Erlangen, 1988), 10–26,
Lecture Notes in Math., 1399, Springer, Berlin, 1989.

[2] Ceresa, G.
$C$ is not algebraically equivalent to $C^−$ in its Jacobian.
Ann. of Math. (2) 117 (1983), no. 2, 285–291.

[3] Nori, Madhav V.
Cycles on the generic abelian threefold.
Proc. Indian Acad. Sci. Math. Sci. 99 (1989), no. 3, 191–196.